# Смена картинки при наведении

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем ошибка? Не могу понять,что делаю не так в простом действии - необходимо,чтобы картинка изменялась при наведении курсора.

```css
.izo {
display: inline-block;}

a.izo:hover {
background: url("other_pic.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;}
```

```html
<a href="/add/"><img class="izo" src="/pic.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Тегу `img` нельзя применить свойство `background`!
- У тега `img` уже по-умолчанию задано `display: inline-block;`

Можно применить смену фоновых изображений к ссылке.

Как один из возможных вариантов:

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

a:hover img {
  opacity: 0;
}

a:hover {
  background: url("http://wpguru.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/CSS-Logo-214x300.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<a href="/add/">
  <img class="izo" src="https://www.w3.org/html/logo/downloads/HTML5_Logo_256.png">
</a>
```

Comment: ого,вот это провал. Каким образом тогда лучше это сделать?

Answer (score 2):

Вы картинку на HTML добавляете через `img src`, а пытаетесь изменить свойство `background` в `CSS`

Вам нужно картинку добавлять с помощью `CSS` в класс izo

```
.izo {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url("pic.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;}
}

a.izo:hover {
    background: url("other_pic.png") no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
```

Comment: Т. е. HTML должен выглядеть таким образом? <a href="/add/" class="izo"></a>

Comment: @Alla, Elena Semenchenko написала как нужно сделать, опередила)